# Drawing pairs (planar graph, circle packing)

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, generative-art

[Circle packing theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_theorem) states:

*For every connected simple planar graph G there is a circle packing in the plane whose intersection graph is (isomorphic to) G.*

**How to use Mathematica to draw examples of such pairs (planar graph, circle packing)?**

More specifically, the requirements of my question could be formulated as follows:

*Generate a random connected simple planar graph with given number of nodes $N$ (this can be done lets say using adjacency matrix; in a way another parameter affecting resulting graph could be "density" of links). Draw its usual graphical representation containing nodes and links. Then draw its circle packing representation.*

---

In other words, a solution could contain a slider for $N$, and a slider for the "density"  (those two variables are parameters). Based on values of these sliders, get regular drawing of a random graph with given $N$ and density, and also drawing of its circle pack.

---

NOTE ON GENERATING RANDOM PLANAR GRAPHS:

To my knowledge, this is not a trivial problem, and there is no built-in Mathematica solution. Though, there are several questions and answers here. One of best is [Create triangular mesh from random list of points](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22211/create-triangular-mesh-from-random-list-of-points/22220#22220) :

```
SeedRandom[1];
pts = RandomReal[{0, 12}, {100, 2}];
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"];
dt = DelaunayTriangulation[pts];
dt // Column
toPairs[{m_, ns_List}] := Map[{m, #} &, ns];
edges = Flatten[Map[toPairs, dt], 1];
Graphics[GraphicsComplex[pts, {Line[edges], 
  Red, PointSize[Large], Point[pts]}]]
```

---

NOTE ON GENERATING CIRCLE PACK CORRESPONDENT TO A PLANAR GRAPH:

See: [Collins, Stephenson: A circle packing algorithm](https://www.google.rs/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&ved=0CHAQFjAG&url=http://www.researchgate.net/publication/222403200_A_circle_packing_algorithm/file/50463521dfbd4a3c58.pdf&ei=aTRxU5_GD8ec0QW6x4DoCQ&usg=AFQjCNEEp_EJyMyfmDTikDCOnWdlNAm-ig&sig2=pU0zLPnoVh_U1GP868ln2A&bvm=bv.66330100,d.d2k&cad=rja).

---

Visual examples:

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

This question is not an assignment. It is an intellectual experiment, related to aestetics and structure. I am not requesting code. I am seeking ideas, approaches, and solutions.

Comment: This question is too broad. Please be more specific.

Comment: And please, this is not a feature/code-request site. It would be much more motivating for others if you showed what you already tried. Plus, if it is an assignment, add the appropriate tags.

Comment: @Yves Klett, it would be much more motivating for askers if they were not welcomed with such accusatory tone.

Comment: It was not intended to be accusatory, but personally I feel it is polite to show previous efforts. Just to clarify: is it an assignment or not? Just to get the tags right. If it is not, please accept my apologies, but verbatim pasted paragraphs often carry that notion.

Comment: ViviD, I don't think @YvesKlett's comment was accusatory, given that you generally ask questions without demonstrating what you've tried (code). I'm sure that you're actually capable of writing _Mathematica_ code and that you actually tried a few things, but users have no way of divining your intentions or your abilities so it is incumbent upon you to show your efforts.

Comment: @VividD I'd like to see you *answer* some questions so that I know you are not here only to take.  Though I speak only for myself I imagine others feel the same way.  (Nevertheless it is an interesting question, with or without effort shown, and it has my vote.)

Comment: @rm-rf: Actually, looking at VividD's contributions to the site so far, I see zero evidence that they are capable of writing Mathematica code or have any interest in learning to do so.

Comment: None of the asked question had a relevant code in it. Even [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47570/1356) question had its code taken from an [other place](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hamming_numbers). To me, it doesn't fit in the "_you should show what you have tried first and you will get an answer._". It's more like "_Hey! I have to do this, it's interesting so please do it for me?_".

Comment: @VividD Hi ! I wanted to let you know that making minor changes is not the way to improve a Q/A. You have to look for something big and work on it, not just change from lower to upper case letters

Comment: @Sektor Thanks for the point! But I never submitted just change from lower to upper case except perhaps in my own posts.

Comment: @VividD I may have missed that :) Nevertheless, the edits should be substantial, otherwise they will probably get rejected

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I bought *'Introduction to Circle Packing'* by Kenneth Stephenson a few years ago,
and have been trying to understand it since. I found the`FindMaximum`answer by @SimonWoods very
good, but larger graphs slow that algorithm down, as he said.

@VividD said "I am not requesting code" and "I am seeking ideas, approaches,
and solutions". I finally have the code, but there is a lot of it. Therefore,
here is a description of one approach based on my interpretation of Stephenson.

The key is to break the problem into two halves.

**First:** ***Find radii without placing any circles.***

Find the radii of all circles such that the combinatorics of the graph are
satisfied. That is, find radii such that the distance between adjacent nodes i
and j is radii[[i]]+radii[[j]], for all i and j, i $\ne$ j.

Stephenson (page 244) describes the uniform neighbour algorithm to iteratively
find these radii. For any node $V$ in the graph, adjust its current radius by
multiplying it by $b (1-d) /(d (1-b))$, where $b=\sin(t/(2k))$, $d=\sin(\pi/k)$, $t$ is
the angle sum, and $k$ is the number of neighbouring nodes surrounding $V$.
The angle sum (pages 15, 57) is the total angle subtended at the central node
$V$ by adjacent pairs of surrounding circles labelled with their current, as yet
approximate, radii. An angle sum greater than $2\pi$ means the central circle
radius is too small, causing the surrounding circles to overlap. An angle sum less
than $2\pi$ means the central circle radius is too large, producing gaps between
the surrounding circles. An angle sum of $2\pi$ is just right, the $k$ surrounding
circles are pair-wise tangent.

The uniform neighbour algorithm of Stephenson cycles through each interior
node, adjusting the radius corresponding to that node. Multiple cycles
through the interior nodes enables convergence to a stable set of radii.

**Second:** ***Find the circle centres corresponding to their radii.***

Once the radii are found, place any two adjacent circles, a and b, such that
their centres are separated by the sum of their radii, that is, they are tangent.
Then place a (positively oriented) triangular face by finding the position of
the centre of the third circle c which makes a mutually tangent triple with these two placed circles. This process generates two new pairs of placed circles, (c,b) and (a,c), leading to placements of new third circles, triangular face by face.

Following this outline, plus some compiling and memoization, I was able to
construct circle packings of 1500 circles in about 125 s. Finding the radii
is by far the most time-consuming part.

Rendering is the easy part:

[image: CirclePack]

Comment: I wonder if this is the same as the algorithm described in [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_theorem#Algorithmic_aspects) which is the first link in the question?

Comment: It is indeed. Have I wasted bandwidth? I hope there is some value added with the explicit expression for the modified value of the central radius r...

Comment: No no, I was just curious if it was the same or whether there was some subtlety that I missed.

Comment: This is great! This answer required a lot of effort and expertise! There is a big difference between reading algorithm description (in Wikipedia or elsewhere) and knowing that it actually works, how it works, where its strong and weak points are, etc! I wonder if you could post some more results, perhaps for graphs mentioned here. Maybe you could export results and place them in a dropbox shared folder?

Comment: @KennyColnago, I have some suggestions: It would be nice if you take all planar graphs from Mathematica curated data (using GraphData[]; there are several thousand such graphs, I believe), and export both original graph drawing, and the circle pack obtained by your code.

Comment: The purpose of this will be twofold: 1) The algorithm will be tested. 1a) The implementation will be tested. 2) Everybody will have the opportunity to explore visual harmony(or chaos) and mystery of results.

Comment: This will also provide an insight and a tool for possible modifications and improvement of the algorithm. (you will get lets say a lot of performance data)

Comment: Similar to a benchmark test...

Answer (score 32):

Two versions of a solution to this question will be presented. Both are applications of built-in Mathematica optimization tools. The key point of both version is the choice of optimization goal and constraints (or, in another words, model formulation).

Interested reader may find article [*Configuration Analysis and Design by Using Optimization Tools in Mathematica*](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v10i1/contents/OptimizationTools/OptimizationTools_4.html) by FRANK J. KAMPAS and JÁNOS D. PINTÉR useful. It is not about the problem from this question, but deals with solving geometric problems using Mathematica's optimization tools. There are also several related questions on thus site.

## First version

This will surely be hopeless for large graphs, but here's a crude approach using `NMinimize`. The aim is to minimize the difference between the inter-vertex distance and the sum of their radii, and also the offset distance between the vertex positions in the original and final graph.

Let's say heptahedral-5 graph is chosen as the original graph:

```
g = GraphData[{"Heptahedral", 5}]
```

[image]

This code will produce its circle packing, using `NMinimize` in appropriate setting:

```
n = VertexCount[g];    
pts = Table[PropertyValue[{g, i}, VertexCoordinates], {i, n}];    
rads = Array[r, n];
xs = Array[x, n];
ys = Array[y, n];

f1 = Total[(r[#1] + r[#2] - EuclideanDistance[{x[#1], y[#1]}, {x[#2], y[#2]}])^2 & @@@ EdgeList[g]];
f2 = Total[MapThread[({#1, #2} - #3)^2 &, {xs, ys, pts}], -1];

rules = Last@NMinimize[f1 + 0.1 f2, Join[rads, xs, ys]];

circles = MapThread[Circle[{#1, #2}, #3] &, {xs, ys, rads} /. rules];
g2 = Fold[SetProperty[{##}, VertexCoordinates -> {x[#2], y[#2]} /. rules] &, g, Range[n]];

Show[Graphics[circles], g2]
```

[image]

## Improved version

This is an improved version which seems to cope with larger graphs. This is still based on black box optimization but with some changes:

- Use `FindMaximum` instead of `NMaximize` to find a local maximum.
- Circles which should be touching (i.e. graph edges) are put in as constraints, i.e. sum of radii == distance between centres.
- All other pairs of vertices (non-edges) are placed as far apart as possible - the sum of these distances is what we maximize.

Also, in this example, I've used a Delaunay triangulation (as suggested in the question) to create a simple random planar graph (however, using an undocumented `DelaunayMesh` function.

Other steps are also marked and described by comments in the code:

```
Graphics`Region`RegionInit[];
dist[{a_, b_}] := Sqrt[(a - b).(a - b)];
n = 30;

(* get a random mesh *)
pts = RandomReal[1, {n, 2}];
m = DelaunayMesh[pts]["MeshObject"];

(* get edges and non-edges *)
edges = Sort /@ m["Edges"];
nonedges = Complement[Subsets[Range[n], {2}], edges];

(* variable lists *)
rads = Array[r, n];
pos = Array[{x[#], y[#]} &, n];

(* set up constraints for edges *)
cons = (Total@rads[[#]] == dist@pos[[#]]) & /@ edges;
cons = Join[cons, Thread[rads > 0]];

(* define function to maximize *)
f = Total[dist@pos[[#]] & /@ nonedges];

(* variable initializations *)
vars = Join[rads, Flatten[{pos, pts}, {2, 3}]];

(* do the maximization *)
{posv, radsv} = {pos, rads} /. Last@FindMaximum[{f, cons}, vars];

(* result *)
Graphics[{MapThread[Circle, {posv, radsv}],
  Opacity[0.5, Green], Line[posv[[#]] & /@ edges]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Great application of Mathematica built-in optimisations! Thanks a lot! I am also curious why do you think that in FindMaximum vs NMaximize, FindMaximum wins for larger graphs? (Or maybe this is not the case?)

Comment: for your first method, I tried g = GraphData[{"BananaTree", {7, 4}}] , with all other code the same, the resulting circle pac is not entirely correct for some reason...

Comment: The original algorithm is not very good - it doesn't *constrain* the circles on connected vertices to touch, it just attempts to minimize the gaps. At the same time it is trying to minimize the movement of the vertices from their initial positions (which is not really what we want to do). So it reaches a point where it will sacrifice the circle-packing in order to avoid rearranging the vertex positions.

Comment: The second version improves things by using constraints to *insist* that the circles on connected vertices touch each other. The original vertex positions go in as a starting point to `FindMaximum`, which seeks a **local** maximum (whereas `NMaxmimize` looks for a **global** optimum). It can still give unsatisfactory results, with overlapping circles for non-edges. I think this means that `FindMaximum` has found a local maximum which is not a global optimum. I guess this could be remedied with more constraints.