# How to randomly create disks with randomized radii under given specific cover ratio?

Tags: graphics, random

I want to create uniformly distributed disks(dots) in a specific rectangular area.

Suppose:

1. the disk radii should be uniformly between $a$ and $b$ ($0<a<b$); there is no interaction between any two disks;
2. the cover ratio $r$ is defined as the ratio of total area of all dots to the area of the rectangle.
3. $a$ and $b$ decreases(increases?) accordingly with the increase of $r$

How to establish a mathematical model and obtain the desired graphs?

There is basically no criterion except for the `visual effects` of  the example figures below; I have thought of using `VoronoiMesh` function but the visual effects may be different.

So constructive proposals or codes which generates similar visual effects will be accepted.

Here are example figures:

[image]

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51097/1356)? Probably a dupe.

Comment: thank you! It seems how to calculate the radii of disks are also critical